# highlight both section and subsection in the outline on the side of a beamer slide

Tags: beamer

Currently only subsection highlighted on the outline on the side of the slide. Is it possible to change the template so when in a subsection the respective section stays highlighted.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Hannover}}
\begin{document}
\section{1}
\subsection{a}
\begin{frame}
stuff
\end{frame}
\subsection{b}
\begin{frame}
more stuff
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behaviour is not limited to the theme `Hannover`, it concerns all themes using sidebars. To change it, you have to patch the macro `\insertverticalnavigation`, which is responsible for generating the sidebar navigation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Hannover}}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\insertverticalnavigation}%
{\ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}\else{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}\fi}%
{{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{1}
\subsection{a}\frame{}
\subsection{b}\frame{}
\section{2}
\subsection{a}\frame{}
\subsection{b}\frame{}
\end{document}
```

The code in ll. 4-9 changes the default behaviour of `beamer` to always highlight the current section (with the `beamer` theme `section in sidebar` in contrast to `section in sidebar shaded`) - normally, the section is only highlighted if no subsections are shown in the sidebar, i.e. if you have `\usetheme[hideallsubsections]{Hannover}`.

#### The resulting sidebar with highlighted section (cropped):

[image: sidebar with section "1" and subsection "b" highlighted]

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm! I dumped it into the main theme `sty` file so that it is hidden from the user.