# Adding background color to active sections of beamer sidebar

Tags: beamer, color, backgrounds, themes

I have designed a theme for my beamer presentation which has sidebar in it.
Now I want to add background color for active items in the sidebar. How can I do that?

Following picture shows what I intend to do.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are not providing a MWE I'm using a standard sidebar theme to show what you need to do in principle. If you need something more specific for your use case please provide a MWE with your code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetheme{Hannover}

\setbeamertemplate{section in sidebar}{\tikz{\node[fill=black!80,text=white]{\insertsectionhead};}}

\begin{document}
\section{first}
\begin{frame}
this is a test  
\end{frame}
\section{second}
\begin{frame}
this is a test 2  
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can customize the appearance as much as you like by styling the `TikZ` node.

---

If you also want sections to be highlighted when there are subsections (by default Beamer shades a section when it has subsections), you need to add the following code to your preamble (kindly provided by [@diabonas](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/65028/24483))

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\insertverticalnavigation}%
{\ifx\beamer@nav@css\beamer@hidetext{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}\else{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar shaded}}\fi}%
{{\usebeamertemplate{section in sidebar}}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This does not work well when the section title is longer than the width of the sidebar -- then the section title in the tikz node is not properly wrapped. It gets even worse when changing the size of the font, e.g. ``\setbeamerfont{section in sidebar}{size=\fontsize{10}{10}\selectfont}`` -- then the position of the section title changes as well. Do you know of any simple fixes for these cases?